# Trigger javascript on child from parent window, and run in child context

Tags: jquery, forms

So, I am trying to open a second window, so that a download can be triggered from it, rather than the current form.

In the parent window, I open a child window with:

```
var windowHandle = window.open("../Downloading.aspx", "_blank", "height=200, width=200,alwaysRaised=yes", false);
```

I then add a form (downloadReportForm is a jQuery object with the form) to the downloading.aspx page

```
$(windowHandle.document).ready(function () {
    var $oldForm = $('form', this);
    alert($oldForm.length); //1

    $oldForm.after(downloadReportForm);
    var $excelReport = $('form#excelReport', this);

    alert($excelReport.length); //1
    $excelReport.submit();
});
```

It looks like it works, however, it still seems to trigger the form as though it is coming from the parent window, rather than the child.

What I am trying to accomplish is a small "please wait for your download" window.  The form has to be generated client side, and then triggered.  It works if it's contained in one page, but when I try and put the form in the newly created/opened window, it doesn't run in the new window.

Any idea how I can perform this feat?

EDIT: It looks like the problem is actually with appending the form to the new window...it's being appended to the current window, not the new one.

EDIT2: Not sure why I can't append this form to the body...

```
$(windowHandle.document).ready(function () {
    var $body = $(windowHandle.document.body);

    //FAILING to append...getting an exception
    $body.append(downloadReportForm);

    var $excelReport = $('form#excelReport', $body);                    
    $excelReport.submit();
});
```

The jQuery variable $body has a length of 1.  But the append line fails saying "no such interface".

Comment: Why don't you put that code inside `Downloading.aspx`?

Comment: I just googled `Trigger javascript from child window` and I found plenty of answers. Did any of those not work for you?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli, because the form object is dynamically created elsewhere, and I'm trying to add it to the downloading page, then trigger it.

Comment: Why the separate window (wouldn't this get blocked from pop-up blockers)? Why not just redirect to a new page that shows the "Please wait for your download..."?

Comment: @Jeff, I screwed up the title, I'm not trying to trigger javascript from a child, I'm trying to add a form to a child window, and have it be submitted from the child window.  However, after more research it appears my problem is in adding the form to the child window...that part is what is not working.

Comment: @normalocity, no, it won't be blocked by pop-up blockers, it's an internal app.  And I don't want to redirect, the user is still performing tasks on the current page.  Which is why I'm trying to open a new window, add a form to it dynamically, and trigger it to submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is that I wasn't creating the downloadReportForm properly

I was just creating elements using `$('<input ... />');` when if I want to add them to another document, they need to be created in that documents context using `$('<input ... />', windowHandle.document);`

Answer (score 0):

From the child, use `opener.` before your function call.

example: `opener.alert("moo")`